# For which values is $x^3$ less than or equal to $3x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The title says it all. The answers say:

$x\le -\sqrt{3}$ and $0\le x\le \sqrt{3}$

(can someone edit this so all the $<$ have an 'or equal to' sign. Edit the roots as well please.

I'm not sure how to attempt this question. When I simplify, I get $x^2\le 3$, so $x\le  \pm\sqrt{3}$.

Thanks!

Comment: For $\le$ you want `\le`; the plus-or-minus sign is `\pm`, and the square root is `\sqrt{3}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality can be solved very easily.

$$x^3< 3x\iff  x(x^2-3)< 0 $$

If $x<0, x^2-3>0$

As $x^2-3>0\implies$ either $x>\sqrt3$ or $x<-\sqrt3$

and as $x<0$ the required region will be $x<-\sqrt3$

Similarly, if $x>0, x^2-3<0\implies -\sqrt3<x<\sqrt3$

and as $x>0$ the required region will be $0<x<\sqrt3$

---

Alternatively,

HINT:

$$x^3< 3x\iff  x(x-\sqrt3)(x+\sqrt3)< 0 $$

This will hold true if odd number (one or three) of factors $< 0$

Now check for the ranges $(-\infty,-\sqrt3);[-\sqrt3,0);[0,\sqrt3);[\sqrt3, \infty)$

Comment: I got:
$x \le 0$, $x \le -\sqrt {3}$, $x \le \sqrt {3}$
What did I do wrong?

Comment: @missiledragon, how have you simplified ? Please find the edited answer

Comment: Alright, if there was a similar question, but it had an $x^2$ instead of $x^3$ would you need to test for both greater than or less than $0$?

Comment: @missiledragon, $a\cdot b<0\implies$ either $(a>0$ and $b<0)$ or  $(b>0$ and $a<0)$  So, try to prove $(x-a)(x-b)<0$ where $a<b\implies a<x<b$

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the first explanation. If $x<-\sqrt{3}$ or $x>\sqrt{3}$, and it's known that $x<0$, then $x<-\sqrt{3}$, not $-\sqrt{3}<x<0$.

Comment: @GlenO, thanks for your observation.Rectified.